# Extraxt the Data into Different Column into Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table which having many row around 70000.
Table consist of 3 different data i.e.

```
 work number,cell number and home number
```

So i want to extract the data in 3 different Table which query shoud i use?

Comment: Why do you want to break up the phone data into separate tables?  The current table seems fine to me.

Comment: Hey, @Rohit Ghongade. Welcome to SO. Your question seems a little confusing to me. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe if you give us some context, it's more likely you'll get an answer. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask the right way.

Comment: Do you mean split 1 column which contains 3 phone numbers into 3 columns which each contains 1 number?